Eventos com Emojis (Discord.js)
Então, estava tentando fazer com que ao clicar no emoji do embed, um simples console.log acontecesse, eu falhei miseravelmente. Este código usa uma API de pokemon, estou basicamente tentando criar uma pokedex. Vocês conhecessem alguma forma de quando o usuário clicar no emoji, algo aconteça?
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');



module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('pokedex')
        .setDescription('Retorna dados de um Pokemon')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('nome_pokemon')
                .setDescription('Insira o nome do Pokémon') 
                .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {

    const pokemon = interaction.options.getString("nome_pokemon")
    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`)
    const poke_data = await response.json()
    let poke_name = poke_data.name;
    poke_name = poke_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + poke_name.slice(1);
    const poke_image = poke_data.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default;

    const descUrl = poke_data.species.url;
    const descResponse = await fetch(descUrl);      
    const descData = await descResponse.json();
    const poke_desc = descData.flavor_text_entries.find(entry => entry.language.name === 'en').flavor_text;
    
    let poke_types = poke_data.types.map(type => type.type.name);
    poke_types = poke_types.map(type => type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1));

    const typeUrl = poke_data.types["0"].type.url
    const typeResponse = await fetch(typeUrl)
    const typeData = await typeResponse.json()
    let double_dmg_names = typeData.damage_relations.double_damage_from.map(double_dmg_from=> double_dmg_from.name)
    double_dmg_names = double_dmg_names.map(double_damage_from => double_damage_from.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + double_damage_from.slice(1))


        
const pokedex = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('Red')
    .setTitle(`${poke_name}`)
    .setDescription(`${poke_desc}`)
    .setThumbnail('https://64.media.tumblr.com/9b521d7ea0df3175f4821022c504e231/716cd31c60495dbd-05/s250x400/8bcd348f1e026c7df95aee10f935f98249b0da16.pnj')
    .setImage(`${poke_image}`)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Type', value: `${poke_types}`, inline: false },
        { name: "Weakness", value: `${double_dmg_names}`, inline: false},
    )
    const embedEnviado = await interaction.reply({embeds: [pokedex], fetchReply: true});
        await embedEnviado.react("");
        

    },
};

